# Test deployment failed for indirect reference assembly not found, Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I am new to unit testing. 
I was trying to run a simple unit test in Visual Studio 2008. The code I was testing uses a third party library. When I try to run the test, following error occurred.

"Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'nunit.framework' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container .... "

So I think, the library I am using has reference to nunit.framework. Should I install nunit or any better way to solve it?

Regards,
Thanks.

Comment: Are you using nunit or ms test? Do you have a code sample

Comment: I am using MS test. But the problem is from the third party assembly I used in my code. I don't have the source code for that assembly though.

Comment: Weird - A third party lib shouldn't include test dll's and why would anybody include a reference to a unittest dll in a shipped library. Maybe you could disable the warning with a #pragma statement in your tests (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/441722ys(v=VS.90).aspx)